# Do attribute assignment operators need to be declared in NAMESPACE? How?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have a package with a function `foo` which uses `rlang::fn_fmls()` and `rlang::fn_fmls()<-`:

```
#' @importFrom rlang fn_fmls missing_arg
foo <- function(x) {
  args <- rlang::fn_fmls(x)
  args <- c(args, bar = rlang::missing_arg())
  rlang::fn_fmls(x) <- args

  return(x)
}
```

Using roxygen2, I obviously need to document this function with an `@importFrom rlang ...` in order to get those functions declared in my NAMESPACE. However, does the inclusion of `fn_flms` there also handle the declaration of `fn_fmls<-`? Or does it also need to be included separately? If so, how? `@importFrom rlang fn_fmls<-`? `"fn_fmls()<-"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fn_fmls<-` is an entirely separate function, an example of what is a called a [replacement function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html), which you can read more about at the link. The gist is it must take the form `function_name<-`, and always returns a modified version of its first argument.

We can see in the `rlang` documentation that `fn_fmls<-` takes two arguments, `fn` and `value`. The function is used to replace the formal arguments of `fn` with `value`. Using a very simple example, if we only import `fn_fmls`, we get:

```r
#' @importFrom rlang fn_fmls
foo <- function(values) {
  fn <- function(a = 1, b = 2) A + B
  fn_fmls(fn) <- values
  fn()
}

foo(list(A = 10, B = 20))
#> Error in fn_fmls(fn) <- values : could not find function "fn_fmls<-"
```

Instead, if we import `fn_fmls<-`, we get:

```r
#' @importFrom rlang `fn_fmls<-`
foo <- function(values) {
  fn <- function(a = 1, b = 2) A + B
  fn_fmls(fn) <- values
  fn()
}

foo(list(A = 10, B = 20))
#> [1] 30
```

Note that we didn't have to import `fn_fmls`. This is because again, the similar naming is just a convention of convenience, since `fn_fmls` is a function to retrieve formal arguments of a function, it makes logical sense to name a function to replace formal arguments of a function `fn_fmls<-`, since it will be written as `fn_fmls(fn) <- value`.